# Why my game crashes when I open Agent Contract page in Valorant?

Tags: valorant

I am facing an issue with my **Valorant** game for about 2 months now. Whenever I open agent contract page in Valorant, it crashes. At first, the contract for **Omen** was activated, and I thought its only for omen that the game crashes. However, now **Neon** contract is activated and game still crashes. This is the error I always got.

[image: error]

I am sick of this crashing. Help me out. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you've done a reinstall already?

Comment: Nah. Though its fully updated.

Comment: Should I reinstall it?

Comment: Give it a try! Should be one of the first things to try for errors like this

Comment: Alright. So, I have to sacrifice my 2 days for not playing the game as my internet is like a snail; slow and not steady.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred to me this morning when I played an Unrated Match. The issue comes up either when your computer runs low on RAM or the internet connection is unstable. The issue can be resolved by rebooting the launcher,
Riot Client. However, if your Riot account is being shared with another person, it might be the case if both of you are trying to log in.

If the above does not resolve the problem, try to go to settings on the Valorant lobby and adjust your resolution. This helps relieve GPU and CPU usage. Closing unused applications also help.